# Are there limits similar to Google Analytics 7 dimensions in Facebook Ads and Twitter Ads?

Tags: twitter, google-analytics, facebook-ads-api

I am fetching data from Google Analytics, Facebook Ads and Twitter Ads, I have found there is a limit of 7 dimensions for Google but not what are for Facebook and Twitter.

Is there any limit in records or dimensions for the Ads api's on Facebook and Twitter?

Comment: Have you tried checking their documentation what does it say?

Comment: Yes I did, there is no confirmation or refutal of any limit, and i don't have access to an account with enough data to test it